# Which it is the oxidation state of indium and phosphorus?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state, solid-state-chemistry

I would like to know what the oxidation state of indium and phosphorus in a structure type rock salt. It could be +1 and -1? Yes or not? and why?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You don't need oxidation states of +1 and -1 to make a rock salt structure.  Magnesium oxide does it with +2 and -2.  In any event indium phosphide actually does not have the rock salt structure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium_phosphide).

Comment: Under pression there is a phase transition from zinc blende to rock salt for this system.

Answer (score 0):

I've estimated net atomic charges in rocksalt type InP by simple HF calculation in CRYSTAL06 in random basis.
Lattice parameter of 5.54 A is taken from:

K Kabita et al. First principle study on pressure-induced electronic structure and elastic properties of indium phosphide (InP). Indian J. Phys. (2015), DOI 10.1007/s12648-015-0701-0.

Results: http://pastebin.com/zdb8js8Z

Total atomic charges are 47.2861139, 16.7138861, so partial charges are:

```
In: +1.71
 P: -1.71
```

Given that oxidation state is an hypothetical charge that an atom would have if all bonds to atoms of different elements were 100% ionic, the answer is probably better estimated as **+2/-2**, not 1.